# Change the user agent of an Object?

Tags: javascript, html, user-agent

I want to change the user agent of my Object to offer the possibility to preview mobile of a website in the desktop browser.

```
 <div style="width: 320px;height: 564px; overflow: visible;">
            <object type="text/html" data="**URL**"
                    style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            </object>
    </div>
```

Is it possible ?
is there a way to provide a preview mobile for a webSite?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean with object? The browser? The requests?

Comment: i mean the div.object

Comment: I think he means the `object` tag.

Comment: My fault, that was obvious...As far as I know the user-agent is defined in the navigator, wich is unique in a window. Maybe you can use an iframe instead an object and then modify the user agent within that iframe

Comment: With Object or iFrame i can't find a solution to my problem